# react-snap, confusion about re-rendering after the static page loads?

Tags: react-snap

I'm trying react-snap and it works in that pages are turned into static versions and served, but then React loads and then re-loads/re-renders everything.

1) Is this expected or is there any way to prevent the re-load / re-render after React loads?
2) How does this work with SEO - will Google get the static version, index it, then later run the JS and index that React JS version later on?
3) What will Google consider the load time to be? The initial pre-rendered static page or the time to download the JS and re-render the page?

What I have are routes that points to a listing, where the actual content is retrieved from an API call.  e.g. /listing/1, /listing/2, etc.

In the React component, I have a ComponentDidMount() that retrieves the listing details from the API call and the render() method uses these details in its rendering.